# setPreloadSprite not working and results in image not displaying

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I don't see why this code isn't working. I load the images in a booter state, add the sprites in the preloader state, but `setPreloadSprite` ends up making the image not even appear.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J5fUE/115/

What am I doing wrong? Phaser 2.2.1

Also, I am planning on having 2 different loading images. Is it possible to `setPreloadSprite` for multiple sprites/images?

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(500, 500, Phaser.CANVAS, 'game_div');
var gameStates ={};
var hello;

gameStates.booter = function(){};
gameStates.booter.prototype = {
    preload: function(){
        game.world.setBounds(0,0,500,500)
       game.load.image('hello', 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads-1969f46zwpmbh5cm3kr2/hello.png'); 
    },
    create: function(){        
        game.state.start('preloader'); 
    }
}

gameStates.preloader = function(){};
gameStates.preloader.prototype ={
    preload: function(){
        hello = game.add.sprite(150, 150, 'hello');
        game.load.setPreloadSprite(hello);
    },
    create: function(){
    }
}

// Add and start the 'main' state to start the game
game.state.add('booter', gameStates.booter);  
game.state.add('preloader',gameStates.preloader);  
game.state.start('booter');
```

Comment: if you add some stuff to load, its seems to work: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/J5fUE/118/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code / jsfiddle that I can see. The reason it doesn't appear is that you're not loading anything. If I add a bunch of load calls into your Preloader preload method then it fills up as normal for me as they load.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason is that all of your **assets are coming from cache**.

You can verify if this is the case by going to `Chrome Developer Tool > Network`. If your assets are coming from cache they will display "from cache" in the Size column.

What I did to see my progress bar is check the "Disable cache" option and refresh the page. This will ensure that all assets are loaded from their source and trigger the progress bar.

[image]